# NodeJS: net.connect returns null/undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

My plan is to write a Query "class" in NodeJS which connects to a server and sends some data.

The following error occurs:
[image: Error]

*My Query.js*

```
var net = require('net');

function Query(ip,port,user,pass,sid){
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.sid = sid;
        this.dataString = "";

        this.socket = net.connect(port,ip,function(){
            this.socket.write("login "+user+" "+pass+"\r\n");
            this.socket.write("use "+sid+"\r\n");
        });

        this.socket.on("data", function (data) {
            this.dataString += data.toString();  
        });
}

Query.prototype.test = function(){
    this.socket.write("logview\r\n");
}

module.exports = Query;
```

This is the part where I create an object (index.js):

```
var srvleinQ = new Query(config.Serverlein.adress,config.Serverlein.port,config.Serverlein.user,config.Serverlein.pass,config.Serverlein.sid);
srvleinQ.test();
htmlData = srvleinQ.dataString;
```

**IP,Port and login data are correct!**

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You should use promises.

Comment: Isn't the callback function the correct way, to wait until the connect finished?

Comment: Yes, but you then try to access it outside the callback before it finished.  That cannot work.  You can't escape from callbacks.

Comment: Oh well, what you say seems obvious. Thanks, now it works. But: Why did it work in in the callback, when it wasn't in the extra module? First I tested the connection without the module, only in index.js.

Comment: Because the callback only runs once the response arrives.